# SSRS Report Server Download Not Working

Tags: internet-explorer

This is an issue that just started happening.

Typically in Report Manager if you click on the Download link in a specific report you will be prompted with the usual IE11 download dialog "Do you want to open or save [reportname].rdl?" with the usual Open, Save, or Cancel options.

Now I get prompted with "Do you want to open or save Report_aspx?ItemPath=[reportpathdetails]?" The Open, Save, and Cancel buttons don't work.

I've checked compatibility view and that does not appear to be the problem.

The issue is restricted to my PC. Everything works normally on other clients.

Web searches mention ReportingServices.js being corrupt but I have flushed my cache to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Edit: Uploaded screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Edited question with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is just Internet Explorer trying to be helpful!

Using the example in your screenshot, click on Save.

Within IE, click on "View Downloads" option.

Looking at the file you have just downloaded, right-click on it.

Uncheck the option "Always ask before opening this type of file."

Comment: The problem isn't that simple. When I click on Save the dialog box appears but when I click on the Save button on the dialog box nothing happens. Nothing is saved the dialog remains open. Looking at View  Downloads reveals a whole list of options to save or open none of which works.

Comment: Disable  your anti-virus? This is not an SSRS issue. Try resetting your version of IE - it could be a setting you have inadvertently changed.

Comment: First, I appreciate your interest. Yes, I know it's a setting; I was hoping someone could tell me what setting.